# Is there any way to detect which hardware the input came from in web programming?

Tags: php, jquery, html, hardware

I am developing a barcode reader application for personal use (inventory). The barcode reader I am using, acts like a keyboard, it inputs the barcode number and sends an "Enter". However, I always need to focus manually said text field.

I want to make the reader update the whole form of fields when it reads a barcode. Without having to place the focus manually on the field.

In order to do so, I was wondering if there's a way to determine if the keypress (or another event) came from the bar reader or from the keyboard?.

The development it's currently done under HTML/JS (jQuery) and PHP, but I'm not closed to other suggestions.

The barcode reader is plug and play, and didn't come with drivers. Is there a way to read the information on the device that is performing the input?

Comment: Perhaps detecting the time between character entry? If the average gap is inhuman you could assume it was the barcode reader.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838559/detecting-input-from-bar-code-readerand-rfid-from-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @GreatBlakes: no diff between scanning and cut 'n pasting, though.

Comment: @MarcB does cutting and pasting get registered character by character then?.

Comment: there is "onpaste" to detect it. but unless the scanner's been configured with a decentish inter-char delay, it's likely to be detected with similar inter-char spacing as a normal keyboard "held key" input rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of differentiating a (generic) barcode reader from a real keyboard. You may solve your problem by adding a keypress handler on a page with code that sets focus to the field you need to put the value into.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the autofocus attribute in the html.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp

Comment: That works for the first time I load the page, but I'm trying to do it at different times also. I'm trying to redirect the input to the corresponding field if it comes from the reader. Thanks either way.